# Get all files in folder S3 Amazon in one request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need one help!

I need get all files in folder S3 amazon, but in one request
in my s3-bucket i have 3 objets
models/one.sldprt
models/two.sldprt
models/three.sldprt

In this time, i can get one object, about this code:

```
public byte[] getS3Object(String key) {
        AmazonS3 s3Client = getClientS3();
        String bucketName = "mybucket";
        S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(bucketName, "models/one.sldprt");
        S3Object object2 = s3Client.getObject(bucketName, "models/two.sldprt");
        S3Object object3 = s3Client.getObject(bucketName, "models/three.sldprt");
    try {
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(object.getObjectContent());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

have the method to get all files in folder in one request?

Comment: What do you want to return?  You've got a single `byte[]` currently and you return the contents of a single file.

Comment: What do you mean by "get all files"? What do you want to do with them -- download them? Return their contents? More information, please.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Amazon S3 currently doesn't have a batch GetObject API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TransferManager class as recommended in AWS documentation. Please refer [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-transfermanager.html) for more details. Although I think this is only supported in SDK ver 1.x.

Here's the sample code copied from the above link:

```
TransferManager xfer_mgr = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().build();

try {
    MultipleFileDownload xfer = xfer_mgr.downloadDirectory(
            bucket_name, key_prefix, new File(dir_path));
    // loop with Transfer.isDone()
    XferMgrProgress.showTransferProgress(xfer);
    // or block with Transfer.waitForCompletion()
    XferMgrProgress.waitForCompletion(xfer);
} catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getErrorMessage());
    System.exit(1);
}
xfer_mgr.shutdownNow();
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `ListObjectsRequest` should do though you need to change your return value (this is V2 of the Java SDK):

```
public List<byte[]> getS3Object() {
        S3Client s3Client = getClientS3();
        String bucketName = "mybucket";
        ListObjectsRequest listObjects = ListObjectsRequest
                .builder().bucket(bucketName).prefix("models/").build();

        ListObjectsResponse listObjectsResponse = s3Client.listObjects(listObjects);

        List<byte[]>    fileContents = new ArrayList<>();

        for (S3Object s3Object : listObjectsResponse.contents()) {
            GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = GetObjectRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName).key(s3Object.key()).build();
             
            ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse> getObjectResponseResponseBytes = s3Client.getObject(getObjectRequest, ResponseTransformer.toBytes());

            fileContents.add(getObjectResponseResponseBytes.asByteArray());
        }

        return fileContents;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This loops through all items in a bucket, reads them into a `byte[]` and saves each one to a List.  It returns the content of each file.

Answer (score 0):

Tanks about the awsears.
After then much study, i arrive in the simple solution.
In my case, i need get more than 100 arquives from aws.
I found the price about the query. Is insignificant.

Because this, i make the paralles querys... and i get very fast the arquives.
Show the code:

get one file method:

```
public byte[] getS3Object(String key) {
    try {
        AmazonS3 s3Client = getClientS3();
        S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(awsConfig.getBucketName(), key);
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(object.getObjectContent());
    }catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        throw new AwsProxyCredentialException(EXCEPTION_MSG_PROXY, e);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        if(e.getMessage().contains("The specified key does not exist.")){
            String msg = String.format(EXCEPTION_KEYNOTFOUND,key);
            throw new AwsException(msg, e);
        }else{
            throw new AwsException(EXCEPTION_MSG, e);
        }

    }
}
```

get async method

```
@Service
```

public class AwsServiceS3Async {
private final AwsServiceS3 awsServiceS3;

```
public AwsServiceS3Async(@Lazy AwsServiceS3 awsServiceS3) {
    this.awsServiceS3 = awsServiceS3;
}

@Async
public Future<byte[]> getS3ObjectAsync(String key){
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(awsServiceS3.getS3Object(key));
}
```

}

call end method

```
        public Page<ModelDTO> filterDtoByIds(List<Long> modelIds, Pageable pageRequest) {
    String modelsIdsToRsql = modelIds.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    String rsql = String.format("id=in=(%s)",modelsIdsToRsql);
    Filter filterParam = new Filter();
    filterParam.setRsqls(Arrays.asList(rsql));

    Page<Model> filter = this.filter(pageRequest, filterParam);
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    List<ModelDTO> modelDTOS = filter.getContent()
            .stream()
            .map(model -> modelMapper.map(model, ModelDTO.class))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<Future<ModelThumbnailsWrapper>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    modelDTOS.forEach(modelDTO -> {
        futures.add(modelServiceAsync.getThumbnailsAsync(modelDTO.getId()));
    });

    futures.forEach(feature ->{
        try {
            ModelThumbnailsWrapper mtw = feature.get();
            modelDTOS.stream()
                    .filter(modelDTO -> modelDTO.getId().equals(mtw.getId()))
                    .findAny()
                    .ifPresent(modelDTO -> modelDTO.setModelThumbnails(mtw.getModelThumbnails()));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new AwsException(e.getMessage(),e);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new AwsException(e.getMessage(),e);
        }
    });`

    Page<ModelDTO> result = PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(
            modelDTOS,
            pageRequest,
            filter::getTotalElements
    );
    return result;
}
```